# r list force to recycle items

Tags: r, list

noob question;)
how do i force a list to recycle condition in function?
when i run

```
mylist <- list(a = 3, b = c(2,8), c = c(1,4))
sumit<-function(v){x<-v$a + v$b + v$c}
x<-sumit(mylist)
```

it of course correctly returns 6 & 15 (recycling mylist$a). But if I want to run

```
sumit<-function(v){
  x<-v$a + v$b + v$c
  if (v$c ==1) x<-x*100
  }
x<-sumit(mylist)
```

It does not want to recycle condition and uses for both case `mylist$c = 1` resulting in 600 & 1500 instead of 600 and 15

How do you force it to recycle arguments? I have seen recycle function from rebus library but it conflicts with several other packages I use, and I do not want to move `$c` to arguments as I do not know in the process which element of the list will have what length - sometimes c might have 3 values, sometimes b etc.

And I do not want it to split into sumit(a,b,c) by separating the list into 3 vectors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `ifelse` :

```
mylist <- list(a = 3, b = c(2,8), c = c(1,4))
sumit<-function(v){x<-v$a + v$b + v$c}
x<-sumit(mylist)

sumit<-function(v){
  x<-v$a + v$b + v$c
  x <- ifelse (v$c ==1, x*100,x)
}
x<-sumit(mylist)
x
# [1]  600 15
```

`if` works with single length logical, and takes the first element in other cases, `ifelse` works with vectors.

Comment: it still returns 600 & 1500 instead of 600 and 15 - the condition is not recycled (thank you for edit)

Comment: thank you, it perfectly resolves the problem given. I had no idea about ifelse, thought I was an equivalent to if then else

Comment: is there anything that works with vectors longer than 2 or is it matter of nested ifelses only? I mean like 'case' - i know r does not have case by definition

Comment: I don't understand your question, the condition (first vector) can be as long as desired, the 2nd and 3rd arguments must be vectors of the same length as the condition

Comment: sorry, incorrectly phrased, the original problem had something like if c == 1 s<-"a", else if c == 7 s<-"b", else if c == 15 s<-"d". is the only option ifelse c==1(ifelse c==7,'b','c'),'a') etc or is there more elegant solution

Comment: just asking as my problem has several ifs inside, but that's probably another topic

Comment: `dplyr::case_when` is the function you might want for this case